# Get element SVG child as text in Vaadin

Tags: java, html, svg, vaadin, element

I have an SVG element created using javascript inside a div with a specific ID. My primary goal would be to get the SVG image to let the user download it.

So my idea, which may absolutely be wrong, was to access the Div element (I'm using Vaadin 23), with `container.getElement()`, get the child element, which is my SVG and do `svgElement.getOuterHTML()` to obtain the string and save it somewhere. I can see the element and I know it's there, but when I print my container element from vaadin it doesn't have any children.

My situation:

```
<div class="chart-container" id="chart-div-02250ca9-3b1b-4d09-aeb2-f38c4c797fc9">
    <div>
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" role="group" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: visible;">
        ...
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I get from `content.getElement().getOuterHTML()`, where `content` is my div with the ID:

```
<div id="chart-div-02250ca9-3b1b-4d09-aeb2-f38c4c797fc9" class="chart-container">
</div>
```

What am I missing?

If this is the expected behaviour, how would you go about getting the SVG element? I tried with JS and then returing the result to Java but it was a real mess with Futures and all than synchronous stuff.

**EDIT** (adding clarification on final goal):
The final goal is as follows: I want to add a feature where the user can download the rendered SVG as an image. But the thing is that I "build" the SVG at runtime, so I can't save it somewhere before the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin does not automatically sync child elements created client side with JavaScript or the template content to the server. This is simply because adding such implementation would be really problematic from performance point of view, while it is very rarely needed.

What you can do, is to implement your component as `LitTemplate`. That allows you to inject selected elements from the template using `@Id` annotation

```
@JsModule("./my-template.ts")
@Tag("my-template")
public class MyTemplate extends LitTemplate {

@Id("svg")
Element svgElement;

...
}
```

While the "frontend/my-template.ts" is something like

```
import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';
import { customElement } from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('my-template')
export class MyTemplate extends LitElement {

render() {
   return html`
<div class="chart-container" id="chart-div-02250ca9-3b1b-4d09-aeb2-f38c4c797fc9">
    <div>
        <svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" role="group" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: visible;">
        ...
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>';
}
}
```

Note however, there is no deeper support for Svg elements in Vaadin, so I am not sure what you can achieve with this.

So eventually the question is, why you need it? And answer to that question may reveal other avenues for you.

Edit: As it turned out that you want to programmatically compose SVG and then download it, the answer to the original question wont help. Another kind of methods needs to be used.

One possible avenue is to compose SVG server side using String fragments. Here is an example of random polyline. With this approach you have the SVG data in server side all the time, and you can hold it in a String, which you can download easily.

```
Html createChart(String color) {
    Random random = new Random();
    List<Integer> data = random.ints(300, -100, 100).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    String svg = "<div><svg class=\"uk-animation-stroke\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%; --uk-animation-stroke: 100000;\" preserveAspectRatio=\"none\" viewBox=\"0 -100 600 200\"><polyline points=\"";
    int index = 0;
    for (int number : data) {
        svg += index + "," + number + " ";
        index += 2;
    }
    svg += "\" style=\"stroke-width: 1;fill:none;stroke:" + color
            + "\"></polyline></svg></div>";
    Html chart = new Html(svg);
    chart.getElement().getStyle().set("height", "100px");
    return chart;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was clearly missing a lot of information regarding how vaadin renders web pages. 
The final goal is as follows: I want to add a feature where the user can download the rendered SVG as an image. But the thing is that I "build" the SVG at runtime, so I can't save it somewhere before the execution.

Comment: The thing I explained is giving just a handle to the element, so that you could e.g. modify its styles or something like that. But you wont get the raw SVG image content for export via that, i.e. wont help you to download the image.

Comment: What you are asking is non-trivial to build from the scratch. There is SVG builder component in the Vaadin's Directory. But it lacks the export function. Adding one to it could be possible. The add-on possibly needs an update for Vaadin 23 as well. https://vaadin.com/directory/component/svg-component

Comment: OK thank you, I'll try again and get back to you if I find a viable solution